# Question closed as a duplicate without duplicate added

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I am surprised. This question [closed as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331261/show-all-images-only-after-their-complete-load), but there is no duplicate assigned to it. How can this be?

Comment: That is genuinely puzzling, one the closers even admits it was closed incorrectly 3 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time the question was closed, the "this question is a duplicate" text was literally added to the bodies of questions closed as dupes. Strange, but true. The OP of this particular question felt that the it *wasn't*, in fact, a duplicate, and [removed the text](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7331261/revisions). I see that animuson just added it back.

This happened a bunch. At some point, a few years back, the dupe text was made unremovable.